# Emploi métaphorique du mot « Golgotha » pour signifier une grande souffrance

Tags: usage, religion, métaphore

L'autre jour, jái parlé d'une collègue dont la fille et l'époux sont gravement malades.

J'ai dit alors :

> Mme X a vraiment un grand fardeau ; voire un Golgotha à monter.

Il m'a fallu expliquer de quoi je parlais. L'emploi métaphorique du mot « Golgotha » est-il accepté ou pas de nos jours ?

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/golgotha

Comment: je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression, en France du moins. C'est peut-être utilisé dans d'autres pays de la francophonie

Comment: Il s'agit d'une référence manifestament chretienne - il est fort possible qu'elle est inconnue aux personnes, qui ne sont pas trop religieuses ou surtout qui ne sont pas chretiennes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le mot *[golgotha](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/golgotha)* est attesté avec un G minuscule (donc en tant que nom commun). Mais ce n'est pas du tout un mot courant et [il est le plus souvent écrit avec une majuscule](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Golgotha%2C+golgotha%2C+golgother%2C+golgothe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGolgotha%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgolgotha%3B%2Cc0) (c'est-à-dire que c'est un nom propre). Je ne sais pas s'il est accepté au Scrabble (sur le web j'ai trouvé les deux affirmations contraires). C'est plus une référence culturelle qu'un mot de la langue et ce n'est pas une référence culturelle très connue.

En revanche, le terme [calvaire](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/calvaire) fait partie du vocabulaire courant. *Calvaire* était au départ un nom propre, qui vient de la traduction latine *Calvaria* du nom *Golgotha* (mot qui signifie « crâne » en araméen), mais il est passé dans la langue comme nom commun. Un *calvaire* est une tâche difficile, une grande souffrance. Ce sens du mot n'est pas perçu comme une allusion biblique. On ne « monte » pas un calvaire : le calvaire désigne la souffrance, donc on le subit.

On peut aussi parler de [*chemin de croix*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chemin_de_croix), qui lui est perçu comme une allusion biblique. [*Chemin de croix* est moins courant que *calvaire*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Golgotha%2Ccalvaire%2Cchemin+de+croix&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGolgotha%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalvaire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchemin%20de%20croix%3B%2Cc0) mais la plupart des gens comprendront.

> Mme X a vraiment un grand fardeau, un véritable calvaire.

Comment: L’ODS6 (Officiel du Scrabble, 6e édition, qui a été valide de 2012 à 2015) n’inlcut pas *golgotha*. Je n’ai pas accès aux autres éditions. Il est possible qu’il ait été ajouté à l'ODS7 (2016-2019), voire à l'ODS8 (paru en 2019, officiel à partir de 2020). [Il ne semble pas](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Officiel_du_jeu_Scrabble#Mots_supprim%C3%A9s) qu’il ait été présent dans les éditions antérieures.

Comment: Pour info, il n'est même pas dans le DCLF.

Answer (score 0):

On doit pouvoir l'utiliser, mais comme c'est d'un usage littéraire peu de monde a l'idée de s'exprimer en en usant, probablement, et ce n'est pas très connu. Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/golgotha) mentionne cet usage par métaphore, que l'on trouve chez Flaubert ; il existe même un verbe, « golgother ». C'est beaucoup  utilisé dans la littérature pour parler métaphoriquement d'un lieu ou d'une situation horrible, sordide…

> − P. métaph. N'est-ce pas ici que fut couvée notre douleur à nous autres, le golgotha même où le génie qui nous a nourris a sué son angoisse? (Flaub., Champs et grèves,1848, p. 401).

Il y a aussi le problème de l'introduction du concept dans la conversation : l'idée exprimée par « voire » n'est pas une idée que l'on associerait avec ce qui précède (difficile de dire pourquoi :  « voire » signifie « même », « et même », et l'idée communiquée est de la sorte des renchérissements, donc la logique de base est saine.).

À mon avis il aurait été plus idiomatique de dire quelque chose comme suit.

- Mme X a vraiment un grand fardeau, un Golgotha à monter. (user **LPH**)

*des exemples tirés de la littérature*

- L'escalier à remonter lui était un Golgotha.
- Pour Alain Vircondelet, happé par la houle de Rimb' et sa passion à gravir jusqu'au bout le chemin des mots qu'il se représente comme une montée incertaine vers un Golgotha noir…
- … lorsqu'il me faut grimper un Golgotha de chimères …
- Blessé dans sa dignité, il se disait fatigué d'habiter un musée d'inepties, de gravir un Golgotha.